# JsonUtility.ToJson instantiates null values

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

Using JsonUtility.ToJson to convert my class to Json replaces an array of null classes with an array of instantiated classes. Why?

I have a function that uses

```
string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(m_saveData);
```

and `m_saveData` has `m_playerStatHandler` inside it;

`m_playerStatHandler` has

```
public Equipment[] m_equippedEquipment;
```

where Equipment is a `Serializable` class with `float`s, `int`s and `bool`s inside.

When I run

```
string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(m_saveData);
```

`m_equippedEquipment` is no longer an array of 4 nulls, it becomes an array of 4 default Equipment.

Everything is `Serializable` and has been working for a while, the only issues is that arrays of `null` values are being filled with default classes before I've even loaded. Does anyone know why this is happening and what a solution would be? Cheers

Comment: Could you post a [mcve] please?

Comment: Because it's serializable.

Comment: @shingo This seems to be it. Why is it that serializing an array instantiates it's members, I'm passing it in to be serialized into another object, why is it affecting the original?

Comment: JsonUtility doesn't affect the original, but serialization in Unity happens anytime anywhere. https://docs.unity.cn/Manual/script-Serialization.html (See How Unity uses serialization)

Answer (score 1):

Until now understood the issue.

Indeed every `[Serializable]` type is serialization-wise basically treated as a value type

See [Script serialization -> Serialization rules -> Serialization of custom classes](https://docs.unity.cn/Manual/script-Serialization.html)

> **Inline serialization**: By default, Unity serializes custom classes inline by value when you don’t specify `[SerializeReference]` on the field that references the class. This means that if you store a reference to an instance of a custom class in several different fields, they become separate objects when serialized. Then, when Unity deserializes the fields, they contain different distinct objects with identical data.

and

> Fields can be `null`. Inline serialization can’t represent `null`, instead, it replaces `null` with an inline object that has unassigned fields.

So Unity's serializer  - which is used e.g. by the AssetDataBase, Inpsector and also by the built-in JsonUtility - creates instances of any `[Serilizable]` field.

---

If you require those to actually appear in the JSON and after deserialization be `null` you will need to use a third-party library like e.g. [Newtonsoft Json](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@3.2/manual/index.html)